# Dictionary comprehension inside insert() method not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am making a `MappingList` class which is a list implemented as an `OrderedDict`.

This is the `MappingList` class (some methods omitted):

```py
class MappingList(MutableSequence):
    """
    A MappingList is a regular list implemented as a dictionary
    """

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(list(self.seq.values()))

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return self.seq[item]
        except KeyError:
            _traceback_from_none(IndexError, "list index out of range")

    def __setitem__(self, key, value, *, usage=None):
        if key > max(self.seq.keys()) and usage != "append":
            raise IndexError("list index out of range")
        self.seq[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        try:
            del self.seq[key]
        except KeyError:
            _traceback_from_none(IndexError, "list index out of range")

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.seq)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MappingList):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.seq == other.seq

    @classmethod
    def _dict_from_seq(cls, seq):
        return OrderedDict(enumerate(seq))

    def _next_available_slot(self):
        return max(self.seq) + 1

    def insert(self, index, value):  # todo: insert() should not overwrite
        """Insert a value into the MappingList"""
        if index > max(self.seq.keys()):
            raise IndexError("list index out of range")

        for k, v in {k: v for k, v in self.seq.items() if k > index}:
            del self.seq[k]
            self.seq[k + 1] = v

        self[index] = value
```

When I try to insert an item into a `MappingList`, I get the following error:

```py
  File "C:\...\My Python Programs\free_time\mappinglist.py", line 103, in test_insert
    self.li.insert(1, MappingList(["blah", 1, 5.8]))
  File "C:\...\My Python Programs\free_time\mappinglist.py", line 85, in insert
    for k, v in {k: v for k, v in self.seq.items() if k > index}:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Why is this error happening? Does `OrderedDict.items()` return an integer?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but this is why trying to write complex constructs like this are problematic. Separating the two would have made it clear which part was incorrect, and would make it a lot easier to print the intermediate results and/or set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesn't happen due to that.

When you don't provide `keys(), values(), items()`, python iterates over the keys by default. You need to provide `items()` to tell python to get the keys and values.

```
for k, v in {k: v for k, v in self.seq.items() if k > index}.items():
```

Comment: Oh yeah! I totally forgot to add `.items()`